# Custom ArrayAdapter repeating part of the list over previous list

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have a custom ArrayAdapter that I have an issue with the views I am creating programatically displaying on top of other views.  My XML list layout has certain fixed views and then I am adding other views dynamically depending on the object.  It is only the views that I am adding dynamically that are repeating.  Obviously when the the view is being recycled it is not clearing the views like the others are.  But after extensive searching I cannot find any examples of creating views dynamically inside the arrayAdapter.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

CustomArrayAdapter.java

```
public class CustomArmyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CustomArmy> {
GridLayout mGrid;
// View lookup cache
private static class ViewHolder {

}

public CustomArmyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CustomArmy> armies) {
    super(context, 0, armies);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    CustomArmy army = getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.individual_army_view, parent, false);
    }
    mGrid = (GridLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.armyGridContainer);

    TextView armyNameView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.army_name_value);
    armyNameView.setText(army.getName());

    int row = buildArmyCountAndIconViews(army);

    TextView townHallLabelView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.townHallLabel);
    GridLayout.LayoutParams paramTHLabel = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
    paramTHLabel.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(row);
    paramTHLabel.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(0, 3);
    paramTHLabel.setMargins(0,10,0,0);
    townHallLabelView.setLayoutParams(paramTHLabel);

    TextView townHallValueView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.townHallValue);
    GridLayout.LayoutParams paramTownHall = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
    paramTownHall.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(row);
    paramTownHall.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(3, 2);
    paramTownHall.setMargins(5,10,0,0);
    townHallValueView.setText(army.getTownHallRequired());
    townHallValueView.setLayoutParams(paramTownHall);


    Button loadButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.loadButton);
    GridLayout.LayoutParams loadParam = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
    loadParam.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(row + 1);
    loadParam.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(2, 3);
    loadButton.setLayoutParams(loadParam);



    return convertView;
}

private int buildArmyCountAndIconViews(CustomArmy army) {
    int column = 0;
    int row = 1;

    for (LinkedHashMap.Entry<String, Integer> armySet : army.getArmyValuesMap().entrySet() ) {
        buildArmyIconView(armySet.getKey(), column, row);
        buildArmyCountView(armySet.getValue(), column, row);
        if (column < 9) {
            column++;
        } else {
            column = 0;
            row += 2;
        }
    }


    return row + 3;
}

private void buildArmyIconView(String iconName, int column, int row) {
    ImageView iconView = new ImageView(getContext());
    GridLayout.LayoutParams iconParam = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
    iconParam.height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 25, getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    iconParam.width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 25, getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    iconParam.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(column);
    iconParam.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(row);
    iconParam.setMargins(7,10,0,0);
    iconView.setImageResource(getIconFromName(iconName));
    iconView.setLayoutParams(iconParam);
    mGrid.addView(iconView);
}

private void buildArmyCountView(int count, int column, int row) {
    TextView countView = new TextView(getContext());
    GridLayout.LayoutParams paramCount = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
    paramCount.height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 15, getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    paramCount.width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 25, getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    paramCount.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(column);
    paramCount.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(row + 1);
    paramCount.setMargins(7,5,0,0);
    countView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14);
    countView.setText("x" + String.valueOf(count));
    countView.setLayoutParams(paramCount);
    mGrid.addView(countView);
}

private int getIconFromName(String iconName) {
    int iconId = getContext().getResources().getIdentifier(iconName + "1", "drawable", "com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit");
    return iconId;
}
}
```

**Updated code:**

```
public class CustomArmyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CustomArmy> {
// View lookup cache
private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView armyname;
    TextView townHall;
    TextView armyType;
    GridLayout gridLayout;
}

public CustomArmyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CustomArmy> armies) {
    super(context, 0, armies);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    CustomArmy army = getItem(position);

    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.individual_army_view, parent, false);

        holder.armyname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.army_name_value);
        holder.townHall = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.townHallValue);
        holder.armyType = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.armyTypeValue);
        holder.gridLayout = (GridLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.armyGrid);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.armyname.setText(army.getName());
    holder.townHall.setText(army.getTownHallRequired());
    holder.armyType.setText(army.getArmyType());

    buildArmyCountAndIconViews(army, holder.gridLayout);

    return convertView;
}

private void buildArmyCountAndIconViews(CustomArmy army, GridLayout gridLayout) {
    int column = 0;
    int row = 1;

    for (LinkedHashMap.Entry<String, Integer> armySet : army.getArmyValuesMap().entrySet() ) {
        buildArmyIconView(armySet.getKey(), gridLayout, column, row);
        buildArmyCountView(armySet.getValue(), gridLayout, column, row);
        if (column < 9) {
            column++;
        } else {
            column = 0;
            row += 2;
        }
    }
}

private void buildArmyIconView(String iconName, GridLayout gridLayout, int column, int row) {
    ImageView iconView = new ImageView(getContext());
    GridLayout.LayoutParams iconParam = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
    iconParam.height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 25, getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    iconParam.width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 25, getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    iconParam.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(column);
    iconParam.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(row);
    iconParam.setMargins(7,10,0,0);
    iconView.setImageResource(getIconFromName(iconName));
    iconView.setLayoutParams(iconParam);
    gridLayout.addView(iconView);
}

private void buildArmyCountView(int count, GridLayout gridLayout, int column, int row) {
    TextView countView = new TextView(getContext());
    GridLayout.LayoutParams paramCount = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
    paramCount.height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 15, getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    paramCount.width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 25, getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    paramCount.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(column);
    paramCount.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(row + 1);
    paramCount.setMargins(7,5,0,0);
    countView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14);
    countView.setText("x" + String.valueOf(count));
    countView.setLayoutParams(paramCount);
    gridLayout.addView(countView);
}

private int getIconFromName(String iconName) {
    int iconId = getContext().getResources().getIdentifier(iconName + "1", "drawable", "com.clashtoolkit.clashtoolkit");
    return iconId;
}
}
```

Comment: Where is your viewholder pattern?

Comment: I had not created the viewholder pattern as I cannot figure out how to set that up when you have an unknown amount of views.  So I could create that for the static views, but how do you hold a reference to a view that may or may not exist?  Also, it seems like the viewHolder pattern is mostly to save on the findViewById() calls, of which there would not be any on the dynamically created views.  So implementing that would not solve my current problem.

Comment: Without ViewHolder Pattern, you will stuck on this. The data you have, will repeat itself. You will need more process power. Just read this carefully: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html

Comment: @EphraimSchmitt Are the views you are creating indefinite, or is there a limit to how many views you want inside of one list element (i.e. 0-5 or 1-10)? If so, I would say it would definitely be beneficial to use the `ViewHolder` pattern, and just have as many views in your layout as it takes to match your maximum amount.

Comment: @Bryan, there is up to 24 currently that would be dynamically created within each listView, but that could change in the future.  I try to keep my code as dynamic as possible.  My only issue with the ViewHolder pattern is that I have no idea how to deal with an undefined amount of views.  How would I reference them withing the ViewHolder class?

Comment: @oguzhand  thanks for the link, but it does not help.  I understand the basics of the ViewHolder pattern, but not how to deal with new views that would be created dynamically inside of the custom ArrayAdapter.  If you have thoughts on that let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this is based off of Bryan's answer.  I figured out how to keep it from repeating.  I am deleting all of the view's in the else clause and then recreating the dynamic views.  This solves my issue.  If anyone sees an issue with this let me know, but for now this is what I am going with

**Working Code**

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    CustomArmy army = getItem(position);

    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.individual_army_view, parent, false);

        holder.armyname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.army_name_value);
        holder.townHall = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.townHallValue);
        holder.armyType = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.armyTypeValue);
        holder.gridLayout = (GridLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.armyGrid);
        buildArmyCountAndIconViews(army, holder.gridLayout);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.gridLayout.removeAllViews();
        buildArmyCountAndIconViews(army, holder.gridLayout);
    }

    holder.armyname.setText(army.getName());
    holder.townHall.setText(army.getTownHallRequired());
    holder.armyType.setText(army.getArmyType());

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you implement the `ViewHolder` pattern, I think you should be able to add another `Layout` into your `individual_army_view.xml` file to hold your dynamic views. Then in `getView()` you can add a view to that layout. Like so:

```
public static class ViewHolder {
    public LinearLayout linearLayout;
    ...
}

@Override
public view getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    CustomArmy army = getItem(position);

    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.linearLayout.addView(<yourCustomView>);
    } ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I redid my XML to be a RelativeLayout with a GridLayout inside for the dynamic views.  I then switched my code to reflect this and added the ViewHolder pattern.  This is obviously a lot cleaner and better way to do this.  But my problem still persists.  Thoughts?

Comment: I attempted to put the buildArmyCountAndIconViews() in the first part of the if statement, and that keeps if from layering it on top of each other, but just replaces the views entirely with just that first set of views.